# Replace characters in specific locations in strings inside lists

Tags: python

Very new to Python/programming, trying to create a "grocery list generator" as a practice project.

I created a bunch of meal variables with their ingredients in a list, then to organise that list in a specific (albeit probably super inefficient) way with vegetables at the top I've added a numerical value at the start of each string. It looks like this -

```
meal = ["07.ingredient1", "02.ingredient2", "05.ingredient3"]
```

It organises, prints, and writes how I want it to, but now I want to remove the first three characters (the numbers) from each string in the list before I write it to my text file.

So far my final bit of code looks like this -
[image: Screenshot of final block of code]

Have tried a few different things between the '.sort' and 'with open' like replace, strip, range and some other things but can't get them to work.

My next stop was trying something like this, but can't figure it out -

```
for item in groceries[1:]
    str(groceries(range99)).replace('')
```

Thanks heaps for your help!

Comment: You already know how to use slicing... `"07.ingredient1"[3:] == "ingredient1"`

Comment: I guess I thought I would have to specify the meal variable as well as there's multiple instances of the same ingredient items across different meal variables... if that makes sense?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, no. Please provide a clear example of your expected output, preferably one that demonstrates how my suggestion doesn't work for your use-case.

Comment: Ah, geanakuch put in an answer that I think said what you were trying to say, but in a way I understood a bit more. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item in groceries:
    shopping_list.write(item[3:] + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing you can just take a substring.

```
groceries = [g[3:] for g in groceries]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your general programming knowledge, this solution is maybe a bit enhanced, but [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) would be another alternative.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"\d+\.\s*(\w+)")
for item in groceries:
    ingredient = pattern.findall(item)[0]
```

`\d` means any digit (0-9), `+` means "at least one", `\.` matches ".", `\s` is whitespace and `*` means "0 or more" and `\w` is any word character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9).

This would also match things like

```
groceries = ["1.   sugar", "0110.salt", "10. tomatoes"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> meal = ["07.ingredient1", "02.ingredient2", "05.ingredient3"]
>>> myarr = [i[3:] for i in meal]
>>> print(myarr)
['ingredient1', 'ingredient2', 'ingredient3']
```